# Magento 2: Adding a new Block to Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer

Tags: magento2, blocks

I am trying to add a custom button next to the gift_options, edit, and remove buttons inside the Magento 2 checkout/cart page

Inside my custom theme I have created the Magento_Checkout dir. Inside Magento_Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Actions/NewButton.php

I then added the layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

and add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="cart/item/default.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\NewButton" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.newbutton" template="Mageno_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/newbutton.phtml"
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Then inside my block Newbutton.php I add:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions;

class NewButton extends Generic
{
/**
 * Get item configure url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getConfigureUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/configure',
        [
            'id' => $this->getItem()->getId(),
            'product_id' => $this->getItem()->getProduct()->getId()
        ]
    );
 }
}
```

However when I load the checkout/cart page I run into an invalid block type, class does not exist.

```
Invalid block type:       Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Newbutton
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class    Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Newbutton does not     exist
```

Any advice on how to add this button would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get it done?